# How to get back the Ubuntu 14.10 default login screen

Tags: login-screen

When i lock my PC after successful login it's show the default Ubuntu lock screen but when i reboot my PC it shows the login screen of the theme K Ubuntu that i removed

Answer (score 1):

you can easily do it by following steps

- type the following code in the terminal to reconfigure `lightdm`

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then a dialog box appears to asking to choose the default login manager

  `lightdm` or `kdm` i guess, after that restart the `lightdm` by typing

  ```
  sudo lightdm restart
  ```

or you can do it by the following way

- edit the `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` file by

  pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and typing

  ```
  sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
  ```

and add the following line

```
    [SeatDefaults]

    greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

save the file pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and type `y` and restart lightdm

Comment: You might also want to remove `lightdm-kde-greeter` if that exists

Comment: this didn't helped my situation :( and after entering this command

sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

no dialog box appears

Comment: okay i ran this command

sudo apt-get remove lightdm-gtk-greeter && sudo apt-get install unity-greeter

and i have got the default login screen but the icon[top left] on title bar at login screen show some other icons and after login changes back to normal.